# Method return type hint based on the type of a class attribute

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to set the return type of a method equal to the type of a member of the class itself.

This is the code:

```py
from typing import Type


# interface
class BaseReturnType:
    sender: str = None

class BaseMessage:
    reply_type: Type[BaseReturnType] = None

    def send(self) -> BaseMessage.reply_type:  # here is my problem
        pass


# real implementation
class RealReturnType(BaseReturnType):
    payload: str = None
    more_payload: str = None

class RealMessage(BaseMessage):
    reply_type = RealReturnType


# usage:
rm = RealMessage()
res = rm.send()
print(res.more_payload)
```

Obviously the `BaseMessage.reply_type` does not make any sense...

In the various implementations of `RealMessage`, `OtherRealMessage` (and so on), the `send()` method will return instances of different classes (derived from `BaseReturnType`), but always following the type of the member of `reply_type`.

My temporary solution is to redefine the `send` function every time, just to set its return type. In this way:

```py
class RealMessage(BaseMessage):
    reply_type = RealReturnType

    def send(self) -> RealReturnType:
        return super().send()
```

How can I do that in a better way?

Comment: Maybe you want a [_generic_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics), so `RealMessage` is `BaseMessage[RealReturnType]`?

Answer (score 0):

The technique you're looking for is [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic):

```py
class BaseReturnType:
    sender: str = None

# Declare ``BaseMessage`` as a generic.
class BaseMessage[T: BaseReturnType]:

    def send(self) -> T:
        pass
    

class RealReturnType(BaseReturnType):
    payload: str = None
    more_payload: str = None
    
# Define concrete ``T`` for this class as ``RealReturnType``
class RealMessage(BaseMessage[RealReturnType]):
    pass

rm = RealMessage()
res = rm.send()
print(res.more_payload)
```

If you are using Python 3.11 or earlier, the syntax is slightly different:

```py
...
T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=BaseReturnType)

class BaseMessage(typing.Generic[T]):
...
# This part is the same in both versions:
class RealMessage(BaseMessage[RealReturnType]):
...
```